# RegEx to match text outside of square and curved brackets

Tags: regex, logging

I have a log file that I need to search for. The text outside of the brackets is always the same, so to be as precise as I can, I would like to ignore the text inside both square and curved brackets.

So the log is;

```
[09/May/2022:11:04:05 +0000] NSMMReplicationPlugin - process_postop: Failed to apply update (6278e86f000627440000) error (-1).  Aborting replication session(conn=5361 op=6)
```

Where I do not need the date at the start inside the `[ ]` or the numbers & text inside both sets of `( )` either side of the `(-1)` as the `(-1)` part is key to the search.

I just need to search on;

```
NSMMReplicationPlugin - process_postop: Failed to apply update error (-1).  Aborting replication session
```

I cannot figure this out! I tried a lazy qualifier but as there's `( )` that I need it didn't work;

`(?<=NSMMReplicationPlugin - process_postop: Failed to apply update)(.*)(?=error (-1).  Aborting replication session)`

I somehow need to escape the `( )` to get the `-1` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the following pattern which divides the text into 4 groups and only uses group 2 and 4.

```
(\[.*\])(.*)(\(\w*\))(.*)
```

to get group 2 and 4 we use `\2\4` or `$2$4` depending on the flavour of regex.
See https://regex101.com/r/v6izps/1 for an example.
Depending on the language and the tools there may not be any need to put brackets around the 1st and 3rd groups.